# Save the car position - Geolocalization Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, maps, draggable

I  have a question. In my code I have a draggable marker. I want to move this object to the position of my car and save the position in order that when I open again the app, the car starts in the last position that I selected.

My code is this one:

```
var actualcar;
var car = new google.maps.LatLng(37.41621813281696, -6.155265279129026);
var markercar = new google.maps.Marker({
map:map,
icon: imagecar,
draggable:true,
animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: car
});


function savePosition(){
car=actualcar;
}
```

I have to save the position in actualcar but i don't know how do that .

Can someone help me?
Lot of thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `dragend` event for `markercar` in order to get the position after dragging is finished.

```
var actualcar;
var car = new google.maps.LatLng(37.41621813281696, -6.155265279129026);
var markercar = new google.maps.Marker({
   map: map,
   icon: imagecar,
   draggable:true,
   animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
   position: car
});

google.maps.event.addListener(markercar, 'dragend', function() {
   // actual car will hold google.maps.LatLng object
   actualcar = this.getPosition();
});
```